# How to safely use a param variable to execute an enum search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, brakeman

Consider a User model

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User
   enum status: [:sad, :bored, :happy]
end
```

In a controller, I want to receive `params[:status]` and return all users with that status

i.e.

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController << ApplicationController
   def index_status
      status = "#{params[:status]}"
      if User.statuses.include? status
         @status = status.to_sym
         @countries = User.send(@status)
      else
        redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Invalid status'
    end
end
```

This works fine, but `Brakeman` gives me a `dangerous send - User controlled method execution`  warning for the line

```
@countries = User.send(@status)
```

Is there a way to do this that will not incur a warning from `Brakeman`.

Comment: You should also open an issue for Brakeman, because it doesn't understand enums: https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/issues/new/choose

Comment: Thanks @Justin, I have opened a new issue on Brakeman; https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/issues/1492

Answer (score 1):

From the [ActiveRecord::Enum docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)...

> Of course, you can also query them directly if the scopes don't fit your needs:

```
@countries = User.where(status: @status)
```

---

Note this:

```
status = "#{params[:status]}"
```

Is better written as a call to [`#to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-to_s).

```
status = params[:status].to_s
```

But there's no need to stringify it at all.

```
status = params[:status]
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree, with not needing to stringify it

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment from @Justin, this happens because Brakeman does not understand enums. I have opened a [new issue](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/issues/1492) for Brakeman, and will update this answer when it is resolved.